# A question for postional embedding

Tags: machine-learning

[image]

> This explains why we need both the sine and the cosine for each frequency: if we only used the sine (the blue wave at i   =   100), the model would not be able to distinguish positions p   =   25 and p   =   35 (marked by a cross). 
> Géron, Aurélien. Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow (Kindle Locations 12575-12577). O'Reilly Media. Kindle Edition.

Why doesn't the model distinguish positions p = 25 and p = 35, if sine function is used only?

Isn't it possible to distinguish the positions such that the model refer to other dimension (e.g. other i, 50, 30, etc.)?